# Ctrl+click not working properly

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I am using Windows x64 bit , Texmaker 5.0.3 , basic miktex 2.9.6850 and I compile pdflatex to see the pdf.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click to go to the corrispondent line is working in a weird way. For example if a have phrase and I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click on it brings me to the line corresponding of very beginning of the sentence and NOT to the corrispond line where I clicked. If i go to anothe phrase that 'belong'to a different sentence, separeted by the the previous one by a point, it happens the same with this sentence.
so for exaple if a have a sentence that occupies 100 lines without a point if a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click on a random part of the sentence it would bring to the begininning of it. by the way <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click does not work very well with other parts of text generally.
this is an extract of my code:

```
   \documentclass       [twocolumn,prl,nobalancelastpage,aps,10pt]{revtex4-1}
   %\documentclass[rmp,preprint]{revtex4-1}
   \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{graphicx,bm,times}
    \graphicspath{            {C:/Varie/UNI/MANO/primosemestre/fraboni/esperimenti/RT/pictures/} }
   \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{mwe}
    \begin{document}
```

Comment: Do you have actual linefeeds in the code? Or have you written an entire paragraph without hitting enter, so that the entire paragraph is on the same line in the file? (Looking at the line numbers in Texmaker should make that clear.)

Comment: I get it, it is like you said, thank you. If I do not add enter the text result as a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to :
Tools->Configure Latex->Commands and write this:

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

on Pdflatex .

Answer (score 4):

If @Andrea Angeletti's answer is not enough, it may be due to an accentuated character in the path of the file (see [here](https://www.mathematex.fr/viewtopic.php?t=14115), in French):

> If, for example, your document is in C:\Documents and
> Settings\Propriétaire\My Documents\thesis it will not work because of
> the é in Propriétaire!

The solution is therefore to remove the accentuated character from the path.